# Selecionar registros de uma tabela onde o registro de uma tabela relacionada seja um valor específico

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, select, modelo-relacional, active-record

Tenho uma tabela de chamados técnicos e uma tabela de atendimentos.
Cada 'CHAMADO' possui vários 'ATENDIMENTOS' e é nos atendimentos que fica o campo que define o status do chamado (Aberto, Fechado, Em andamento, Suspenso, etc...)

Atualmente, quando preciso listar apenas chamados abertos, eu estou buscando TODOS os chamados e pra cada chamado eu faço uma nova consulta verificando se o ultimo atendimento é fechado ou não. Essa pratica não é correta.
Como posso, numa query só, buscar apenas os chamados nos quais os ultimo atendimento não seja FECHADO?

Comment: Quais são seus campos de relação de tabela? atendimento nº 5 do chamado º 45

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sem a definição de suas tabelas pode-se apenas sugerir um caminho para a solução. Algo do tipo:

```
SELECT chamados.* FROM chamados 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM atendimentos WHERE atendimentos.cliente = chamados.cliente AND atendimentos.status = 'Fechado';
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o inner join.

```
SELECT c.* FROM chamados c INNER JOIN atendimentos a USING(id_chamado) WHERE a.status <> "Fechado";
```

No caso acima, nas duas tabelas tem que existir o campo "id_chamado" ou o campo que utilizas para fazer a ligação entre as duas tabelas.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

/\ teoria sobre todos os joins.

usando :

```
select campos 
from tabelapai
inner join tabelafilha
on tabelapai.campo = tabelafilha.campo
and tabelapai.campo = tabelafilha.campo
where tabelapai.campo = xx
  and tabelapai.campo = yy;
```

você esta passando 1 comando ao MySQL "selecione campos da tabelapai E ADICIONE A TABELA FILHA quando campos da tabela pai e filha forem iguais ( chaves de identificação ), ONDE O CAMPO DA TABELA PAI SEJA X)

```
select chamados.dados, atendimentos.dados(atendimentos.situacao,chamados.cliente)
from chamados 
INNER JOIN atendimentos 
ON atendimentos.codigo_chamado = chamados.codigo_chamado;
WHERE chamados.situacao = x ;
```

Basta alterar para o código que bem entender, fácil de entender, recomendo a leitura para diferentes tipos de JOIN ( eu usaria `leftjoin` no seu caso para trazer APENAS os chamados que possuem situação fechada MAS NÃO DEIXAR DE TRAZER CHAMADOS QUE ESTEJAM SEM SITUAÇÃO ALGUMA).